# CollectionType custom prototype via form_theme

Tags: symfony

I want to customize the way an entry of a CollectionType in a form will be rendered, that is the way the prototype is generated, I need my own HTML. So I need to do it with the Twig form_theme, but it doesn't work.
I am currently using Symfony 4.1.2.

Here is what I have for now:

In the template that renders the whole form:

```
{% form_theme form.additionalEmails.vars.prototype 'form/additionalEmail.html.twig' %}
```

In the form/additionalEmail.html.twig file:

```
{% block form_row %}
<div style="margin: 10px 0">
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.children.value) }}
    <div>Recevoir les mails de type : {{ form_row(form.children.isUsedForAdminCommChannel) }}{{ form_row(form.children.isUsedForInfosPratiquesCommChannel) }}{{ form_row(form.children.isUsedForAgendaCommChannel) }}</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

If I do that I get this error:

```
 Key "value" does not exist as the array is empty.
```

What is weird is that if I replace the above code by this (by commenting the old one and adding the new line):

```
 {{ dump(form.children) }}
```

I see that form.children is an array with 4 items and one named "value" so it is clearly broken.

Your help would be much appreciated, as I'm just an amateur dev trying to make a website for a youth movement ^^

Best Regards,

[EDIT]
Here is the form that includes the CollectionType:

https://gist.github.com/MrPOC/a4af94cc5e577a1244dac59de5ea3506

The field is named "additionalEmails"

Answer (score 1):

Just so I understand you correctly. You have a Form which contains a `CollectionType` and you want to change the prototype of that `CollectionType`?

If yes could you please post the Form with the `CollectionType`?

EDIT: Ok so here's how to overwrite the prototype template for a `CollectionType`.

First we have to find out what your forms `unique_block_prefix` is. You can find this by going to the page where this form is rendered, you then click in the symfony debug bar on the form icon. Then you have to expand the **View variables** block and look for `unique_block_prefix`.

I assume your block prefix could look like this `_user_type` the name of the block you would overwrite would then be `_user_type_additionalEmails_entry_widget` (for more details please read the link provided below)

You can replace the widget part with *row* or *label* depending on what you want to overwrite (I would suggest trying to overwrite them all to see what exactly changes because I don't know of the top of my head)

In twig you would then take your block prefix and overwrite the prototype field in the same way you would overwrite any other field

```
{% block '_user_type_additionalEmails_entry_widget' %}
    //Content
{% endblock %}
```

What I wrote down here is what I found out after reading https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6056 (read HeahDude' comment specifically)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I updated the post with a link to the form as you asked

Comment: I will test that and come back to you, thanks for your explanations ! :)

Comment: That's some test time :D good answer so upvoted. Thanks